# Intermittent charge on Macbook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, power, applecare, magsafe

I have a 2010 Macbook Pro with a MagSafe T Power adapter.

The power adapter makes a buzzing/hissing/fuzzy noise when it is plugged into the wall.

When it is plugged into my mac, my light turns green for about a second, then orange for 5-10 seconds, and then no charge.

I am not sure if the problem is my Macbook Pro battery, or my adapter?

How can I diagnose/troubleshoot, and what are the best recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the adapter is making a noise when it is plugged into the wall but not connected to the machine then the adapter is probably faulty.

For fault finding you'd normally have two machines and two adapters and you'd try various combinations to rule out which items are working or not.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to take the machine and adapter in to an Apple store and have somebody at the "Genius" bar try a different adapter, battery, etc.

Failing that, I'd guess your power adapter is broken.